How can I change the path in an explorer window with python?
Does anybody know how to  change the current path in an explorer window without opening a new instance with python?
For example if the user has an explorer window open with C:\Users\User. Then I have to change that path to C:\Windows\System32 for example.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can change the working directory using the os module:
import os

os.chdir(path)

Read more about it from the answer to this question here.

Yes, but not the CWD. I meant the path in a graphical explorer window.
